# Can someone identify what is causing this kernel panic?

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

Sometimes my 2019 5k iMac just freezes and tells me it restarted because of a problem. Is faulty ram causing this? I added an extra 8gb ddr4 from Corsair.

```
panic(cpu 8 caller 0xffffff8013c469aa): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8013b5c9db, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xfffffb1d0865f850, CR3: 0x000000036e0940ed, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0xfffffb1d0865f850, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0xffffff801440a1a0, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff821922bdf0, RBP: 0xffffff821922be00, RSI: 0xffffff801440a180, RDI: 0xffffff8055280b30
R8:  0xffffff821922be4c, R9:  0x00000000047868c0, R10: 0x0000003c549af8c2, R11: 0x0000000000000003
R12: 0xffffff8055280b30, R13: 0x0000001d1a949744, R14: 0xffffff8055280b30, R15: 0xffffff801440a180
RFL: 0x0000000000010086, RIP: 0xffffff8013b5c9db, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xfffffb1d0865f850, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x8, PL: 2, VF: 5

Backtrace (CPU 8), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff821922b850 : 0xffffff8013b1a65d 
0xffffff821922b8a0 : 0xffffff8013c54a75 
0xffffff821922b8e0 : 0xffffff8013c465fe 
0xffffff821922b930 : 0xffffff8013ac0a40 
0xffffff821922b950 : 0xffffff8013b19d27 
0xffffff821922ba50 : 0xffffff8013b1a117 
0xffffff821922baa0 : 0xffffff80142c1abc 
0xffffff821922bb10 : 0xffffff8013c469aa 
0xffffff821922bc90 : 0xffffff8013c466a8 
0xffffff821922bce0 : 0xffffff8013ac0a40 
0xffffff821922bd00 : 0xffffff8013b5c9db 
0xffffff821922be00 : 0xffffff8013b5d198 
0xffffff821922beb0 : 0xffffff8013b315b2 
0xffffff821922bf00 : 0xffffff8013c2c065 
0xffffff821922bfa0 : 0xffffff8013ac1226 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: GoogleSoftwareUp

Mac OS version:
19G2021

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu Jun 18 20:49:00 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D3A0F3D-D908-397B-BD16-8F48C0823A2E
Kernel slide:     0x0000000013800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8013a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8013900000
System model name: iMac19,1 (Mac-AA95B1DDAB278B95)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 134044611136
last loaded kext at 33507013351: >!AActuatorDriver  3440.1 (addr 0xffffff7f96989000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver   3.7.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f7
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.ntfs   3.14.3
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.1.0
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.7
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.6
>eficheck   1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!ASMCLMU   212
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.6
@kext.AMD9500!C 3.1.0
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.2.6
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.429
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.140.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f7
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>!UAudio    323.4
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@kext.AMDRadeonX4400HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.1.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f7
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.6
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
@kext.AMDSupport    3.1.0
|IOAVB!F    850.1
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f7
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f7
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.6
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Comment: You should format your post a bit better but your diagnosis seems correct.  Kernel trap -> `page fault` means the kernel failed to read memory at a particular location.  The failure originates from Google Software Update, which is not usually something that would trigger a kernel bug.  This suggests the hardware RAM itself being the problem.

Comment: But before replacing all your RAM I would try removing and reinstalling Google Chrome and/or any other Google software you have installed. Restarting in safe mode will likely also work for turning off the Google software update service.